# MongoDB $lookup pipline with $geoNear

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my collection models:

```
db={
  "user": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ed5525d98980326b5505c0a"),
      "friends": [
        {
          "friend_id": ObjectId("5ed54c3d98980326b5505ad2")
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ed54c3d98980326b5505ad2"),
      "friends": []
    }
  ],
  "geo": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ed54e6a98980326b5505b4b"),
      "user_id": ObjectId("5ed54c3d98980326b5505ad2"),
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          58.631576,
          49.614203
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My task is to write an aggregation in order to get all friends whose distance is less than 400 meters. My aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "friends": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "geo",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "my_geo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$my_geo"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "geo",
      let: {
        "loc": "$my_geo.location.coordinates",
        "uid": "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: "$$loc",
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            spherical: false,
            maxDistanse : 400
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "us_geo"
    }
  }
])
```

Unfortunately, the `near` field in `$geoNear` requires an array and does not want to accept `$$loc`.
In the first step, I get my geolocation, and after using `$lookup` with **pipline** I want to get the geolocation of all my friends closer than 400 meters. Maybe you would advise another model of data storage, which I would not really like, but I hope that you will help to complete the aggregation.
 I sit for a very long time and ask for help from experts. 
I tried many different methods already, and even Google didn’t help me (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found this issue, so for now mongo can’t do that. 
Link to issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34766

Comment: Also, `You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/index.html#behavior